# Pictures in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I'm kinda new in HTML. I'm trying to make a page with HTML where I have text in the left of my page (the lyrics of a song) and then a picture that repeats itself at the right (just beside) of that text. But I want the picture to stop repeating itself at the bottom at some point. I want it to go just the length of the text, so I can write some thing below it, but the pictures just go endlessly. This is how I put the picture in the HTML file:

```
<style>
    
    body
    {
    background:url("../imagenes/augustphotos.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:95% 0%;     
    }
    
</style>
```

Just to clarify: i want the image to repeat itself (one below itself again and again) but then STOP repeating at a certain point.
that's why i used "repeat-y". But with with it just goes on repeating itself, non-stop.
and the possition there (95%) is so it will place at the point i want it in the right of the page (so i can write a text at the left of it)

Also i receive a -1 point, im not very sure why but i'll leave the full code here, in case that was my error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mihojadeestilosTSlyrics.css"/>

</head>
    
<style>
    
    body
    {
    background:url("../imagenes/augustphotos.jpg"); /*La foto de August*/
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:95% 0%;
    }
    
</style>

<body>
    
    <h1><span>August</span></h1>
    
<p>Salt air, and the rust on your door<br>
I never needed anything more<br>
Whispers of "Are you sure?"<br>
"Never have I ever before"</p>

<p>But I can see us lost in the memory<br>
August slipped away into a moment in time<br>
'Cause it was never mine<br>
And I can see us twisted in bedsheets<br>
August sipped away like a bottle of wine<br>
'Cause you were never mine</p>

<p>Your back beneath the sun<br>
Wishin' I could write my name on it<br>
Will you call when you're back at school?<br>
I remember thinkin' I had you</p>

<p>But I can see us lost in the memory<br>
August slipped away into a moment in time<br>
'Cause it was never mine<br>
And I can see us twisted in bedsheets<br>
August sipped away like a bottle of wine<br>
'Cause you were never mine</p>

<p>Back when we were still changin' for the better<br>
Wanting was enough<br>
For me, it was enough<br>
To live for the hope of it all<br>
Cancel plans just in case you'd call<br>
And say, "Meet me behind the mall"<br>
So much for summer love and saying "us"<br>
'Cause you weren't mine to lose<br>
You weren't mine to lose, no</p>
    
<p>But I can see us lost in the memory<br>
August slipped away into a moment in time<br>
'Cause it was never mine<br>
And I can see us twisted in bedsheets<br>
August sipped away like a bottle of wine<br>
'Cause you were never mine<br>
'Cause you were never mine, never mine</p>

<p>But do you remember?<br>
'Remember when I pulled up and said, "Get in the car"<br>
And then canceled my plans just in case you'd call?<br>
Back when I was livin' for the hope of it all, for the hope of it all<br>
"Meet me behind the mall"</p>

<p>Remember when I pulled up and said, "Get in the car"<br>
And then canceled my plans just in case you'd call?<br>
Back when I was livin' for the hope of it all (For the hope of it all)</p>

<p>For the hope of it all<br>
For the hope of it all<br>
(For the hope of it all)<br>
(For the hope of it all)</p>
    
    
<script type="text/javascipt" src="custom.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and then in the css file, there is this for the text:

```
body{position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want the background to be applied to just one element, then you can give that element an `id` and specify the background just for that element.

Comment: Hi! i've had my question resolved now. but i'm new here and i wanted to know, with a "minimal reproducible example" you meant to write the whole code? i edited it and added it just in case that was my error. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to assign the repeating image pattern to the whole page body - which is why it continues forever.
What you should do instead, is to create two DIVs (optionally wrapped inside a third, outer DIV), one for your text, one for the image, and make the CSS applicable only to the one with image.
See this CodePen for an example code:

```css
#outerdiv {
  display: flex;
}

#div1 {
  width: 50%;
}

#div2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489389944381-3471b5b30f04?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv">
  <div id="div1">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
    voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
    tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui
    in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</div>
  <div id="div2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cjkpl/pen/OJpamxW)

Here is your web page with a working side-image:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>

</head>
    
<style>
#outerdiv {
  display: flex;
}

#div1 {
  width: 50%;
}

#div2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489389944381-3471b5b30f04?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
</style>

<body>

    <h1><span>August</span></h1>
<div id="outerdiv">
<div id="div1">
<p>Salt air, and the rust on your door<br>
I never needed anything more<br>
Whispers of "Are you sure?"<br>
"Never have I ever before"</p>

<p>But I can see us lost in the memory<br>
August slipped away into a moment in time<br>
'Cause it was never mine<br>
And I can see us twisted in bedsheets<br>
August sipped away like a bottle of wine<br>
'Cause you were never mine</p>

<p>Your back beneath the sun<br>
Wishin' I could write my name on it<br>
Will you call when you're back at school?<br>
I remember thinkin' I had you</p>

<p>But I can see us lost in the memory<br>
August slipped away into a moment in time<br>
'Cause it was never mine<br>
And I can see us twisted in bedsheets<br>
August sipped away like a bottle of wine<br>
'Cause you were never mine</p>

<p>Back when we were still changin' for the better<br>
Wanting was enough<br>
For me, it was enough<br>
To live for the hope of it all<br>
Cancel plans just in case you'd call<br>
And say, "Meet me behind the mall"<br>
So much for summer love and saying "us"<br>
'Cause you weren't mine to lose<br>
You weren't mine to lose, no</p>
    
<p>But I can see us lost in the memory<br>
August slipped away into a moment in time<br>
'Cause it was never mine<br>
And I can see us twisted in bedsheets<br>
August sipped away like a bottle of wine<br>
'Cause you were never mine<br>
'Cause you were never mine, never mine</p>

<p>But do you remember?<br>
'Remember when I pulled up and said, "Get in the car"<br>
And then canceled my plans just in case you'd call?<br>
Back when I was livin' for the hope of it all, for the hope of it all<br>
"Meet me behind the mall"</p>

<p>Remember when I pulled up and said, "Get in the car"<br>
And then canceled my plans just in case you'd call?<br>
Back when I was livin' for the hope of it all (For the hope of it all)</p>

<p>For the hope of it all<br>
For the hope of it all<br>
(For the hope of it all)<br>
(For the hope of it all)</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
&nbsp;
</div>
<script type="text/javascipt" src="custom.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And here is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: yes!! you resolved my problem, thank you! and now i just need to add another <div> if i want to write something below those text and amage. i should have worked with <div>s since the beginning,  thank you very much!!!